# Fluid particles keep flowing back on curve Force field

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, force-fields

My goal is to have fluid particles pour into a cup and disappear inside. I kept experimenting with multiple settings but the closest solution gave me the result shown below.

The main issue is those particles flowing in reverse and spiraling back down the spiral and not leaving the domain through the cylinder outflow object.

The components of my sim are basic **Inflow/Outflow/Domain/Curve Force Field** and a **Point Force** **field** to try to suck in the particles at the end.

Please help, I've been stuck on this for two days now.

Blend file : [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: tbh simulations, which are a bit more complicated like yours cannot be solved by just some images of showing some settings. The are mathematically pretty complicated and i doubt that anybody can give your precise help why your simulation isn't working. They can guess - that's all. So if you really want to have help, upload your blend file or insert a link to your blend file so we can check it out.

Comment: Alright, file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but in case anyone finds it like I did, the answer for me was increasing resolution divisions, as to a point less divisions means blockier which means less can occupy a given space at one time. More divisions means you don't get that sort of "splash back" if you will